# Business Service Credentials as same as Proxy Service in OSB

Tags: web-services, authentication, proxy, osb

I need to virtualize a WS that has credentials, if I use the soapUI I have to put the credentials in the Request Properties, so after virtualization the authentication must be the same process.

It means I put the credentials in the PS and it has to be passed to the BS and the BS to the legacy service. Any Idea how this can be done?

Comment: Did you try using [Service Account](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/doc.1111/e15867/service_accounts.htm)?

Comment: Yes, I did, but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to pass whatever credentials are provided on front-end to the backend?

For that you need a ServiceAccount with the type **"Pass-Through"**. Assign it to both PS and BS.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to create new User-Account just like any new resource is created from the Create resource option. Once the user account is created it can be tagged to the Proxy or Business Service in the User-account option provided. This would be equivalent to the SOAP-UI thing you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static dvm file [.xq file] that will contain the username and password. That you can pass in proxy or business service as authentication for messages.This would be equivalent to the SOAP-UI thing you are using.